# How to read each line from string in foreach loop instead of each character

Tags: c#

I am trying to read each line to find the state of the HyperV feature, but I just need to read the "State" line, but nothing else. How do I do this? I am currently using a foreach loop, but it only reads each character, so I can't determine if the state is enabled or disabled. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string systemInfo = GetInstalledFeatures.Command("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *Hyper-V-All*");
        foreach (var feature in systemInfo)
        {
            if (feature.ToString().Contains("State")) // The foreach does not read the string, it only reads each character.
            {
                strHyperVStatus = feature.ToString();
                textBox1.AppendText(strHyperVStatus);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The above code is wrong, however the type of feature in the loop is `char`, not `string` and `char` doesn't have a method `Contains` that OP was trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=net-7.0) (needs `using System.Text` at the top of the file):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string systemInfo = GetInstalledFeatures.Command("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *Hyper-V-All*");
    string feature;
    using var rdr = new StringReader(systemInfo);
    while(  (feature = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    { 
        if (feature.Contains("State")) 
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(feature);
        }
    }
}
```

For fun, you could also use this extension method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(this string src)
{
    string line;
    using var rdr = new StringReader(src);
    while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

And then the button_Click method would look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string systemInfo = GetInstalledFeatures.Command("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *Hyper-V-All*");
    var features = systemInfo.EnumerateLines().Where(f => f.Contains("State") );
    foreach(var feature in features)
    {
         textBox1.AppendText(feature);
    }
}
```